# Highlight a cell (weekly) based on the start and end date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to build a project planning doc that automatically highlights the weekly cells based on the start and end dates of the project.

```
----------
Start    End      W1       W2       W3       W4       W5       W6       W7
----------
Date     Date     03/29/14 04/05/14 04/12/14 04/19/14 04/26/14 05/03/14 05/10/14
----------
04/04/14 05/09/14

03/30/14 04/11/14
```

Based on the Start & End date, the respective Weekly should highlight.

Comment: Could you clarify? Which dates should be highlighted (and why)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: in the above example, start date is 4/4 and end date is 5/9. The following cells to be highlighted : W1, W2, W3, W4, W5 and W6.

Comment: Should W1 be highlighted even if it is 3/29 (i.e. before 4/4)? And what about the second dates (3/30 and 4/11)?

Comment: yes, even if it 3/29 the W1 should highlight. Actually the Week start date is mentioned until the next week day starts the previous week should highlight based on the start and end date. Even for 3/30 and 4/11 also should hightlight

Comment: Okay, let's say that the start date is 04/13/14 and the end date is 04/27/14. What weeks should be highlighted?

Comment: W3 to W6. For ex: take 4/13... 4/13 falss under W3 bcoz, it start the week from 4/12 and it ends at 4/18. so, if the the end date is less than equal to 4/18 then, W3 should highlight, or end date is greater than equal to 4/18 then, from W3 to goes on...  I hope I shared good example. :)

Comment: ... I think you meant W3-W5....

Comment: starts from W3 and ends at W6

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using conditional formatting.

Suppose you start your sheet in cell `A1`.
That would mean that your week values would be in cells `C1` (=3/29/14), `D1` (=4/5/14), etc and your first start date would be in `A2` (=4/4/14) and end date in `B2` (=5/9/14).

That being the case, highlight your desired area to be formatted (starting in cell `C2`) and go to:

`conditional formatting` > `New Rule` > `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`

and use the following formula:

```
=AND(C$1<=$B2,D$1>=$A2)
```

(or play around with the `<=` and `>=` to suit how you choose where a week ends / starts)
Then select how you want the cells to be formatted if they meet your criteria and that should do the trick.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you John. But, for the following input (start date 3/3014 and end date is 4/1/14) the above mentioned formula is not working... :( could you please help me out

Comment: You have to explain more... If in cell A3 you have the date 4/4/14 and in cell C2, for example you have the date 3/29/14, it should work....

Comment: the cell A2 contain the start date as 3/30/2014 and the cell B2 contain the end date as 4/1/2014 and the Cell "C1" contain the week start date. If the start and end date falls on the cell "C1" then, that respective C2 cell should highlighted. Hope I gave more clarity.

Comment: Thank you pal.. its working as I required.. for this I've spent two weeks of time.. today only i came to know about this forum and immed I got response. thank you so much again...

Comment: :) - Glad you got it working, @Mr.Light, since you're new, remember to mark it as solved, then.

Comment: Hi Pal, how are you... need ur help again... i'm trying to find out the difference like, if my planned end date is less than actual end date then, the difference date cells should be highlight in color. and plz tell me how to attach a file here. I've a file with data... so, it will help you to clear my question.